# Calculating the total information of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I want to find the total information content of a wavefunction so that I can compare that to its energy but I keep coming up with nonsensical answers.

I know that for a set of $k$ probabilities the equation for information is:

$$S = \sum_i^k{P_n\log_2\frac{1}{P_n}}$$

And I guessed that for a probability density it would similarly be:

$$S=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P(n)\log_2\frac{1}{P(n)}}dn$$

But when I try to substitute in a wavefunction like this

$$\Psi=e^{-\frac{x^2}{\rho^2}}\frac{1}{\rho\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$|{\Psi}|^2=e^{-\frac{2x^2}{\rho^2}}\frac{1}{\rho^2\pi}$$

I end up with negative information. I realized though that the problem was that I was using a density function so I couldn't just substitute $P_n=|\Psi|^2$, but instead I needed to substitute in

$$P_n=\int_{x}^{x+dx}{|\Psi|}^2dx$$

And so

$$S=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(\int_{x}^{x+dx}{|\Psi|}^2dx\log_2\int_{x}^{x+dx}{|\Psi|}^2dx})dx$$

But I'm not sure how, if there is a way, to solve this equation.

Can anyone help me find the information content of a wavefunction?

Answer (score 4):

The proper quantum mechanical notion of entropy is the [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy), defined for a density operator $\rho$ as
$$ S(\rho) := -\mathrm{Tr}(\rho \ln(\rho)).$$
However, for a pure state, $\rho=\rho^2$, so $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho\ln(\rho)) = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho\ln(\rho^2)) = 2\mathrm{Tr}(\rho\ln(\rho))$, so $S(\rho) = 0$.

This is because the "probabilities" that a wavefunction encodes are *not* statistical in the classical sense, but inherent properties of quantum mechanics. In a sense, the entropy measures how much you don't know about the general mixed state that $\rho$ encodes, and for a pure state you *know the state completely*, so there's nothing unknown, and so the entropy vanishes.

Comment: So does that mean all pure states contain zero information? That seems odd given that a particle could be placed in a box with a wall and encode information based upon which side its on. Am I maybe asking the wrong question?

Comment: @AlexanderTaskov No, it means that all pure states have *zero entropy*. "Containing information" is not something that makes any formal sense in physics, so I do not know what you're asking for if you're *not* asking for the entropy.

Comment: I think then that what I'm asking is for the amount of information that can be encoded using some wavefunction.

Comment: @AlexanderTaskov I don't know what you mean by "amount of information".

Comment: How many bits would I need to describe this wavefunction.

Comment: @AlexanderTaskov That depends on how you describe it. How many bits do you need to describe the function $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/\sigma}$? Infinity, because the space of possible wavefunctions is an infinite-dimensional vector space? As many as are required to store the string `e^(-x^2/s)`? As many as you need to store $\sigma$? What if $\sigma$ is irrational, or not computable? You're not asking a well-defined question

Comment: You can ask for relative information between two states.

Comment: It is not entirely incorrect to say that if you know what pure state you have then it contains zero information, since you know everything that could possibly be known about the state in principle. The surprising fact is that some measurements, like for instance finding out if a particle is inside of a box or has tunneled outside of the box, will create NEW information! Information that didn't exist before the measurement was made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your definition is that you're not using a reasonable definition of entropy for probability distributions. Given a probability **distribution** $p(x)$ in position space, the entropy is given by

$$S=-\int\mathrm{d}x\,p(x)\log{p(x)}$$

Thus, if you want to treat the wavefunction as a classical probability distribution, you would want to write

$$S=-\int\mathrm{d}x\,|\psi(x)|^2\log|\psi(x)|^2$$

Let us consider a trial wavefunction

$$\psi(x)=Ne^{-x^2/2\rho^2}$$

Where $N$ is defined so that $\psi$ is normalized (in particular, $N^2=\sqrt{1/\rho^2\pi}$). Then we have

$$S=N^2\int\mathrm{d}x\,e^{-x^2/\rho^2}\left(\frac{x^2}{\rho^2}-\log{N^2}\right)=-\log{N^2}+\frac{N^2\rho\sqrt{\pi}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\log\pi\rho^2+\frac{1}{2}=\log{\frac{\rho}{L}}+C$$

Where $C$ is an irrelavent constant (note that entropy is defined up to a constant and a coefficient of proportionality) and $L$ is some reference scale introduced so that the inside of the logarithm is dimensionless and makes sense.

The only problem with this is that entropy is only defined for **classical** probability distributions (quantum mechanically known as **denisty matrices**).

I hope this helped!